# How many distinct integral value of $n$ satisfies the equation $2^{2n} - 3 \cdot (2^{n+2}) + 32 = 0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many distinct integral value of $n$ satisfies the equation $2^{2n} - 3 \cdot (2^{n+2}) + 32 = 0 $ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: make the substitution $x=2^{n}$ This will reduce your equation to a quadratic.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, So it boils to $X^2 -12x +32 = 0$ solving ${{x -> 4}, {x -> 8}}$ which gives n=2,3. Hence, 2 distinct integral value of n is possible.

Comment: Yep! That's what I got as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to prove a fairly small limit on n.  Think about the fact that 3<2^2.  Then you can just try them all up to there.